# Flask Can I multiple times render_template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I got a Raspberry PI and use a camera to capture pictures. The capture is triggered with a switch on a GPIO port.

The web site (flask; on 127.0.0.1) should show when I trigger the switch and since the saving of the picture takes a while, should also show a wait/ready information.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
```

show a green button on the web, check the GPIO for switches
create my template and

```
render_template('index.html', **templateData)  # seems not to work
```

wait for the existence of the captured image file and 
create an updated template

```
return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

I cannot figure out how I can update the web site twice, while I am waiting for the stored file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be to use the following tag in your template

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

Some more info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

This simply has the page do a refresh every 30secs.

Comment: That doesn't help. I need a green dot (Ready) before the button is pressed and a red one as soon it is pressed, TILL THE PICTURE IS SAVED (that takes about 6 seconds. Maybe I use two pages, one with green dot (Ready), when pressed goes to another page which shows red (wait), ... but even there, how do I switch to green again?